# Stereo Camera Calibration Issues with Point Grey Flea3 cameras on a Jackal Rover

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, jackal, pointgrey, stereo-calibration

We are currently working with a jackal robot from Clearpath Robotics, and we are having troubles with the stereo camera. We can get each individual Flea3 PointGrey camera to work individually, but never together at one time to form a stereo image.

We’ve been running the following commands and getting the data that follows:

Step 1) "roslaunch pointgrey_camera_driver stereo.launch"

… logging to /home/administrator/.ros/log/de9f988a-9360-11eb-bbbf-000babc32460/roslaunch-cpr-j100-0108-5508.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://cpr-j100-0108:45417/

SUMMARY

========

PARAMETERS

** /rosdistro: kinetic*

** /rosversion: 1.12.17*

** /stereo/left/camera_nodelet_l/frame_id: camera_left*

** /stereo/left/camera_nodelet_l/frame_rate: 15*

** /stereo/left/camera_nodelet_l/serial: 17080755*

** /stereo/right/camera_nodelet_r/frame_id: camera_right*

** /stereo/right/camera_nodelet_r/frame_rate: 15*

** /stereo/right/camera_nodelet_r/serial: 16362362*

** /stereo/stereo_image_proc/approximate_sync: True*

NODES

/stereo/left/

camera_nodelet (nodelet/nodelet)

camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)

image_proc_debayer (nodelet/nodelet)

/stereo/

stereo_image_proc (stereo_image_proc/stereo_image_proc)

/stereo/right/

camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)

camera_nodelet (nodelet/nodelet)

image_proc_debayer (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[stereo/left/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [5548]

process[stereo/left/camera_nodelet-2]: started with pid [5549]

process[stereo/left/image_proc_debayer-3]: started with pid [5550]

process[stereo/right/camera_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [5551]

process[stereo/right/camera_nodelet-5]: started with pid [5558]

process[stereo/right/image_proc_debayer-6]: started with pid [5576]

process[stereo/stereo_image_proc-7]: started with pid [5591]

In a new terminal, step 2) "rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --approximate 0.1 --size 7x5 --square 0.025 left:=/stereo/left/image_raw right:=/stereo/right/image_raw left_camera:=/stereo/left right_camera:=/stereo/right"

(‘Waiting for service’, ‘/stereo/left/set_camera_info’, ‘…’)

OK

(‘Waiting for service’, ‘/stereo/right/set_camera_info’, ‘…’)

OK

This Error appears in the first terminal, after step 2)

[stereo/right/camera_nodelet_manager-4] process has died [pid 13862, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/administrator/.ros/log/8375f28a-935e-11eb-b709-000babc32460/stereo-right-camera_nodelet_manager-4.log].
log file: /home/administrator/.ros/log/8375f28a-935e-11eb-b709-000babc32460/stereo-right-camera_nodelet_manager-4*.log
[stereo/right/camera_nodelet-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/administrator/.ros/log/8375f28a-935e-11eb-b709-000babc32460/stereo-right-camera_nodelet-5*.log
[stereo/right/image_proc_debayer-6] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/administrator/.ros/log/8375f28a-935e-11eb-b709-000babc32460/stereo-right-image_proc_debayer-6*.log

We tried changing the nodelet names, but that did not seem to fix anything. Am I missing anything here? Or has anyone heard of this specific error before? Any help would certainly be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/pointgrey_camera_driver says you have to specify the serial number for each camera if more than one is in use at the same time.

You can pass these as arguments on the roslaunch command line. Look in the stereo.launch file for the proper arg names.